# Business-logic type methods in Entity Framework Code First approach classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to know if it is possible to add domain specific methods on model classes which works with Entity Framework Code First approach.

For example, the following *dummy* method:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 

    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    // Dummy method
    public string StudentNamePlusALetter(string letter)
    {
        return (this.StudentName + letter)
    }
}
```

If is not possible, where am I supposed to add them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Code-first is simply classes.

Comment: You can do this, but I worry about separation of concerns.  Also, you won't be able to use that property in any queries against the context, as that operation doesn't exist in SQL.

Comment: What other technique do you suggest?

Comment: You can separate concerns by providing model classes (which are simply containers that map directly to entities (rows) stored in your database) and model "services" that operate on a model class, extending the functionality that upstream callers expect them to provide.  In the above example, you might have a `StudentNameFormatter` class that exposes a `StudentNamePlusALetter()` method (passing in a `Student` and `string` to it).

Comment: Should I extend the model class or create a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is, with the caveat that the value of `StudentNamePlusALetter()` won't be stored in your database (since only properties get serialized down there).

Comment: This is correct for the Method() in the original question, but if you add an extra Property, that has a "setter", then here is more to it.  See my example below.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do this by have 2 "partial" classes.  One for the straight-up mapped database properties.  One for the extra stuff.

In a file called Employee.cs

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public System.Guid EmployeeUUID { get; set; }

    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ? CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

}
```

Then in a file called EmployeeExtended.cs

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1} ('{2}')", this.LastName, this.FirstName, this.SSN);
        }
    }


}
```

Note in the above, I have a readonly ("get") property ("EmployeeFullName") that will work fine with EF, no changes required.

I can also do this:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1} ('{2}')", this.LastName, this.FirstName, this.SSN);
        }
    }

    public string SomeNonTrackedDatabaseProperty { get; set; }

}
```

But then I have to add an ".Ignore" in the Mapping for "SomeNonTrackedDatabaseProperty", since it is not a column in the database..

```
 public class EmployeeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.EmployeeUUID);


            this.Property(t => t.SSN)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(11);

            this.Property(t => t.LastName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Employee");
            this.Property(t => t.EmployeeUUID).HasColumnName("EmployeeUUID");

            this.Property(t => t.SSN).HasColumnName("SSN");
            this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
            this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
            this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("CreateDate");
            this.Property(t => t.HireDate).HasColumnName("HireDate");



            this.Ignore(t => t.SomeNonTrackedDatabaseProperty);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also decorate the property in EmployeeExtended.cs with a [NotMapped] attribute if you want to minimize your the configuration code.

Comment: @txavier   "if you want to minimize your the configuration code"  or "~not separate the concerns of the poco and the orm mapping"   haha!  that's why they give you options.....some prefer one way over another.  i'm a "separation of concerns" peep!  thanks for the alternate method comment.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods won't be a bad idea too here.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect example to use extention methods, with the advantage to keep things separated and well structured.

```
namespace Core.Helpers;

public static partial class Extentions
{
    public static string StudentNamePlusALetter(this Student student, string letter)
    {
        return (this.StudentName + letter); 
    }
}
```

An you can use it the following way:

```
var namePlusLetter = student.StudentNamePlusALetter("A");
```